# Is there a way to write the servo position in angles with Adafruit 1411 Servo shield?

Tags: arduino, adafruit, servo

I'm trying to control my 180 degree servo motors through a Adafruit 1411 Servo shield. However I don't find it simple enough to write the servo's position in angles like the normal servo library without the shield.

Using the Adafruit 1411 Servo shield and Adafruit_PWMServoDriver-library lets you control a servomotor by modifying its pulselength as far as I've realised. To my question..

Is there a way for me to either use the servo shield's output and still write in degrees OR somehow convert these pulselength into angle-degree?

Example of the differences:

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver-library:

pwm.setPWM(Servo, 0, pulseLength);

Servo-library:

Servo.write(45); //Writing in angles like this would be optimal for my project.

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you already tried anything in code?  If so, post it.  If not, this question really has nothing to do with the C tag.  (or any other language tag at this point.)

Comment: How to do this is described in the tutorial for the product. See the bottom of this page: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-slash-servo-shield/using-the-adafruit-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Arduino `map` function. The following is from the Adafruit [instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-slash-servo-shield/using-the-adafruit-library):

```
pulselength = map(degrees, 0, 180, SERVOMIN, SERVOMAX);
```

Where SERVOMIN and SERVOMAX are values you set according to the range of travel of your servo. This linearly maps a value between 0 and 180 into the range between SERVOMIN and SERVOMAX.

Since you've been doing this with pulse widths so far, you probably already knew the values you need to use.